# Send a array in a onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function show(array){
  console.log(array);
}

function main() {
  var send = ["HOLA", "ADIOS"];
  $('#table').append('<tr>'+
                    '<td style="width: 35%">Oscar</td>'+
                    '<td style="width: 6%">'+
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" onclick=show('+send+')>+</button>'+
                    '</td>'+
                '</tr>'
   );
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th style="width: 35%" id="wallet-modal-table-name-header"></th>
   <th style="width: 6%"  id="wallet-modal-table-options-header"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

I have this code and I want to send the array "send" but when I send it as a parameter in the functions it shows me an error. What could I do?

Comment: Embrace the function `addEventListener(event, handler)`  your approach is concatenating the object/array rather than actually passing that array as param.

Comment: Could you upload a snippet please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically created elements, use the Event delegation approach:

```
$(selector4parent).on(event, selector4children, handler);
```

```js
function show(array) {
  console.log(array);
}

function main() {
  $('#table').on('click', '[type="button"]', function(e) {
    var send = ["HOLA", "ADIOS"];
    show(send);
  });


  $('#table').append('<tr>' +
    '<td style="width: 35%">Oscar</td>' +
    '<td style="width: 6%">' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">+</button>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}
main();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width: 35%" id="wallet-modal-table-name-header"></th>
      <th style="width: 6%" id="wallet-modal-table-options-header"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: I try your code but I'm having problems because I have a for and inside the for I'm calling the function send. send(x[i])

Comment: @OscarOrdoñez can you post that logic?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your button outside of the string then append it to the TD you would like it in.

```
var $btn = $(document.createElement("BUTTON"));
$btn.attr({ 'type': 'button', 'data-dismiss': 'modal'}).addClass('btn btn-success');

$btn.click(function()
{
    show(send);
});

$('td-selector').append($btn);
```